# Check to see if 8 comboboxes contain values that match one another excluding null

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

How do I check to see if any of my 8 comboboxes match one another all at once (excluding null values of course, because they are all null when the form loads)? At the moment I have only figured out how to do it for the current and next one. In the case where there is a match, I want to clear the values of all the other comboboxes apart from the one in focus i.e. `currentDropDown`.

Code below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
cboOption2.Enabled = False
cboOption3.Enabled = False
cboOption4.Enabled = False
cboOption6.Enabled = False
cboOption7.Enabled = False
cboOption8.Enabled = False   
cboOption1.Value = Null
cboOption2.Value = Null
cboOption3.Value = Null
cboOption4.Value = Null
cboOption5.Value = Null
cboOption6.Value = Null
cboOption7.Value = Null
cboOption8.Value = Null  
End Sub

Sub rTotal(currentDropDown, nextDropDown)
If (currentDropDown.Value = nextDropDown.Value) Then
    MsgBox "You cannot select the same value twice."
    currentDropDown.Value = Null
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption1_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption1, cboOption2)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption2_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption2, cboOption3)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption3_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption3, cboOption4)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption4_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption4, cboOption5)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption5_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption5, cboOption6)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption6_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption6, cboOption7)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption7_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption7, cboOption8)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption8_Change()
Call rTotal(cboOption8, cboOption8)
End Sub
```

Comment: What application: Excel, Access, Word? Does combobox is placed on the userform?

Comment: Access - and yes. The combobox is placed on the userform

Comment: Have you tried to loop through the collection of combos?

Comment: @MaciejLos - how would you do that, have you got a code sample I can look at at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the collection of comboboxes and check currently selected value to the others.

```
Sub CheckValue(ByVal currCombobox As ComboBox)
Dim ctl As Control, cmb As ComboBox
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            Set cmb = ctl
            If (currCombobox.Value = cmb.Value) And (Not currCombobox Is cmb) Then
                MsgBox "Cannot select it twice!" & vbcr & vbcr & _
                        currCombobox.Name & " = " &  cmb.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

usage:

```
Private Sub CombBox30_Change()
CheckValue CombBox30
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! How about clearing the other checkboxes where the match is found, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (cmb = null), but why to force user to enter data again and again in each combobox? I wouldn't be happy...