# Check to see if combobox values matches more than two times

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to fire an event if a specific combobox value appears more than 3 times ("md") in my control set. At the moment however, I keep getting high values like 32 or 40 despite there only being 8 comboboxes on my Access form. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim mdCount As Integer
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
        Set cmb = ctl
        If (currentDropDown.Value = cmb.Value) And (Not currentDropDown Is cmb) And (Not currentDropDown.Value = "md") Then
            MsgBox "You cannot select the same value twice."
        End If
        If (currentDropDown.Value = "md") Then
            mdCount = mdCount + 1
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing

Private Sub Submit_Click()
'MsgBox mdCount
If (mdCount > 2) Then 
    MsgBox "Error!"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'I keep getting high values'? Is this value assigned to a variable? or in the Locals window?...

Comment: I don't get values within a reasonable range at `MsgBox mdCount`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check to see if 8 comboboxes contain values that match one another excluding null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851145/check-to-see-if-8-comboboxes-contain-values-that-match-one-another-excluding-nul)

Comment: Probably, this is repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly... try something like this (bit hard-coded, but very quick):

```
Function CheckMatches() As Integer
Dim sTmp As String

sTmp = IIf(Nz(Me.Combo1.Value, "") = "md", ";", "") & _
        IIf(Nz(Me.Combo2.Value, "") = "md", ";", "") & _
        IIf(Nz(Me.Combo3.Value, "") = "md", ";", "")  'and so on...

CheckMatches = UBound(Split(sTmp, ";")) + 1
'+1 is necessary in case of Option Base 0, _
'because LBound(array) starts from 0

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim mdCount as Integer
mdCount = CheckMatches
If (mdCount > 2) Then 
    MsgBox "Error!"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Your requirements are not clear, so i can't help more ;(